# How to detect the OS default language in python?

Tags: python

Is there any universal method to detect the OS default language? (regardless what is the OS that is running the code)

```
import os
os.getenv('LANG')
```

The above code works under Linux, does it work under other OS?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use the [`getdefaultlocale` function in the `locale` module](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale).  It returns the language code and encoding of the system default locale in a tuple:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_GB', 'cp1252')
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it OS independent?

Comment: @bank - Yes, I believe so.  Works on Windows and the documentation describes how it works in POSIX environments so you should be fine.

Comment: @Dave_Webb - Works under Linux! I guess mac is considered POSIX compatible!

Btw, shouldn't you update your system to be defaulted to UTF8?

Comment: Strangely it doesn't work for me. Always returns en_US, even on a German version of Windows

Comment: ***THIS FUNCTION REFLECTS THE LOCALE OF YOUR CURRENT LOCATION***

Comment: I am in Brazil using a laptop from a Brazilian company and this function is only sending me as `en_US` location language. I am getting the same output of @banx.

Comment: FYI, `locale.getdefaultlocale()` looks from your environment variable LC_ALL. If you set LC_ALL to something else, `locale.getdefaultlocale()` will return that thing.

Comment: I have never touched my locale env vars (e.g. `LC_ALL`). It is set to an empty string, so when running `locale.getdefaultlocale()` I get the underwhelming tuple: `(None, 'UTF-8')`. Be warned.

Comment: Looks like its getting deprecated: `<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Use setlocale(), getencoding() and getlocale() instead`

Answer (score 52):

Please, **you cannot trust locale module for detecting the OS language** !!!

Whoever used this information without verifying before, will have a program failing over the world, with those users whose OS language is not the same as the region language.

They are different, (1)the OS language and (2)the localization info.

MSDN states that "A locale ID reflects the local conventions and language for a particular geographical region.", http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w60z792.aspx

and python docs,

"The POSIX locale mechanism allows programmers to deal with certain cultural issues in an application, without requiring the programmer to know all the specifics of each country where the software is executed." https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

My Windows7 is in English. But I'm living in Spain so... my locale is 'es_ES'.. not 'en_EN'

I don't know a cross-platform way, for linux you've got it.  For windows I'll give you:

Another post talks about using win32 **GetSystemDefaultUILanguage**, [Find out the language windows was installed as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953416/find-out-the-language-windows-was-installed-as).

But if you want getting the windows language identifier, i recommend to use instead **GetUserDefaultUILanguage()**, because as stated en MSDN, will search recursively until reaches the language:

"Returns the language identifier for the user UI language for the current user. If the current user has not set a language, GetUserDefaultUILanguage returns the preferred language set for the system. If there is no preferred language set for the system, then the system default UI language (also known as "install language") is returned. For more information about the user UI language, see User Interface Language Management."

Code:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('es_ES', 'cp1252')            # <------------- Bad! I'm on english OS.

>>> import ctypes
>>> windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
>>> windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage()
1033
>>> locale.windows_locale[ windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage() ]
'en_US'          # <----------- Good work
```

Comment: To summarise, as mentioned by OP, `os.environ['LANG']` works fine for Linux and Mac. While this solution works for Windows only (module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll' in Unix), an  `if os.name != 'posix'` statement is required.

Comment: On my Win10 , both methods give the same result.

Comment: There are two things in Windows at least, the display language for the OS, and the country or region, which is used to format dates, times, and numbers. So I can have a single language license where the Windows display language is en_US but regional format is en_IN. In my case, the locale module example above gives the locale (en_IN) while the ctypes example gives the OS display language (en_US). So I feel like it's not about it being reliable, but more about what you need to do with this info. If you want to format a date, then locale is better.

Answer (score -5):

Better use windows command line...

```
import os

current_locale = os.popen('systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"System Locale"').read()
```

see
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/132175-see-current-system-locale-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Only valid for windows, it's not a cross platform solution like as OSX.