# How to detect current keyboard language in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, keyboard

My keyboard has 2 keyboard languages that I have been switching , greek and english. How can I get the current keyboard language ?
Ar there any useful libraries that can do the trick for me ?
I have being using python 3.5.2 , Windows 10

Comment: it system information Windows/Linux/Mac. It can depeonds on system which you use.

Comment: Perhaps the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3425316/5209610) to another SO question will help (consult both answers on that post). There's another good [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295271) to this on the Unix SE site.

Comment: @VladislavMartin this returns my default language, not my current !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following approach, utilizing the `ctypes` library, works for me.

```
# My keyboard is set to the English - United States keyboard
>>> import ctypes
# For debugging Windows error codes in the current thread
>>> user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
>>> curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
>>> thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
# Made up of 0xAAABBBB, AAA = HKL (handle object) & BBBB = language ID
>>> klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
67699721
# Language ID -> low 10 bits, Sub-language ID -> high 6 bits
# Extract language ID from KLID
>>> lid = klid & (2**16 - 1)
# Convert language ID from decimal to hexadecimal
>>> lid_hex = hex(lid)
'0x409'

# I switched my keyboard to the Russian keyboard
>>> curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
>>> thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
>>> klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
68748313
# Extract language ID from KLID
>>> lid = klid & (2**16 - 1)
# Convert language ID from decimal to hexadecimal
>>> lid_hex = hex(lid)
'0x419'
```

You can follow the same procedure for Greek (`0x408`), or any other language you'd like to detect. If you're interested, [here is a plain-text list](http://atpad.sourceforge.net/languages-ids.txt) and [here is Microsoft's list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx) of all the hexadecimal values that `lid_hex` could possibly take on, given an input language.

For your reference, LCIDs are stored in [this format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318691(v=vs.85).aspx) (as I described in comments of my code).

Just make sure that you are calling `GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)` every time you switch languages on your keyboard.

EDIT:

As @furas mentioned in the comments, this is **system-dependent**. If you're going to port your code to an OS other than Windows 10 (maybe even earlier versions of Windows, if the LCIDs have changed since then), this approach won't work as expected.

EDIT 2:

My first explanation of `klid` wasn't correct, but thanks to @eryksun's comments I've corrected that.

Comment: Switch to using `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)`. Also, the `HKL` result of [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296) has the language identifier in the low word (16 bits), e.g. `klid = hkl & (2**16 - 1)`. The language identifier consists of the primary language ID in the lower 10 bits and sub-language ID in the upper 6 bits, e.g. 0x409 has a language ID of 9 (`LANG_ENGLISH`) and sub-language ID of 1 (`SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US`).

Comment: `use_last_error` is added here for generality. It protects the thread last error value, in case it gets modified between calling the function and getting the error if it fails. The error value is available as `ctypes.get_last_error()`, which is more reliable than calling `GetLastError` directly. The main purpose of switching to `WinDLL` is to isolate your module from others. `windll` caches libraries, which cache function pointers, and this leads to conflicts when at least one module defines a function's prototype differently from what another module expects, i.e. `windll` is a bad design.

Comment: Your explanation of `klid` is just wrong. 0x4090409 is not 0xAAABBBB, where the language ID is 0xBBBB and sub-language ID is 0xAAA. The language ID is the low word (16 bits, or 4 hex digits), i.e. 0xBBBB, for which the language ID is the low 10 bits of this word and sub-language ID is the high 6 bits of this word.

Comment: The upper word is not something you're using. It's a "device handle to the physical layout of the keyboard". Don't worry about it. Just mask out the low 16 bits -- the language identifier -- as `klid = hkl & (2**16 - 1)`. This will be 0x409 for U.S. English.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for correcting my mistakes using the `ctypes` library. I hope that the edits I've made to my answer have satisfied each issue.

Comment: It does not work on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. And by "not work" I mean that it always returns `67699721`, despite the language. I've tested it via RDP client Remmnina, sitting on Ubuntu notebook.

Answer (score 4):

```
import ctypes

def get_keyboard_language():
    """
    Gets the keyboard language in use by the current
    active window process.
    """

    languages = {'0x436' : "Afrikaans - South Africa", '0x041c' : "Albanian - Albania", '0x045e' : "Amharic - Ethiopia", '0x401' : "Arabic - Saudi Arabia",
                 '0x1401' : "Arabic - Algeria", '0x3c01' : "Arabic - Bahrain", '0x0c01' : "Arabic - Egypt", '0x801' : "Arabic - Iraq", '0x2c01' : "Arabic - Jordan",
                 '0x3401' : "Arabic - Kuwait", '0x3001' : "Arabic - Lebanon", '0x1001' : "Arabic - Libya", '0x1801' : "Arabic - Morocco", '0x2001' : "Arabic - Oman",
                 '0x4001' : "Arabic - Qatar", '0x2801' : "Arabic - Syria", '0x1c01' : "Arabic - Tunisia", '0x3801' : "Arabic - U.A.E.", '0x2401' : "Arabic - Yemen",
                 '0x042b' : "Armenian - Armenia", '0x044d' : "Assamese", '0x082c' : "Azeri (Cyrillic)", '0x042c' : "Azeri (Latin)", '0x042d' : "Basque",
                 '0x423' : "Belarusian", '0x445' : "Bengali (India)", '0x845' : "Bengali (Bangladesh)", '0x141A' : "Bosnian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)", '0x402' : "Bulgarian",
                 '0x455' : "Burmese", '0x403' : "Catalan", '0x045c' : "Cherokee - United States", '0x804' : "Chinese - People's Republic of China", 
                 '0x1004' : "Chinese - Singapore", '0x404' : "Chinese - Taiwan", '0x0c04' : "Chinese - Hong Kong SAR", '0x1404' : "Chinese - Macao SAR", '0x041a' : "Croatian",
                 '0x101a' : "Croatian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)", '0x405' : "Czech", '0x406' : "Danish", '0x465' : "Divehi", '0x413' : "Dutch - Netherlands", '0x813' : "Dutch - Belgium",
                 '0x466' : "Edo", '0x409' : "English - United States", '0x809' : "English - United Kingdom", '0x0c09' : "English - Australia", '0x2809' : "English - Belize",
                 '0x1009' : "English - Canada", '0x2409' : "English - Caribbean", '0x3c09' : "English - Hong Kong SAR", '0x4009' : "English - India", '0x3809' : "English - Indonesia",
                 '0x1809' : "English - Ireland", '0x2009' : "English - Jamaica", '0x4409' : "English - Malaysia", '0x1409' : "English - New Zealand", '0x3409' : "English - Philippines",
                 '0x4809' : "English - Singapore", '0x1c09' : "English - South Africa", '0x2c09' : "English - Trinidad", '0x3009' : "English - Zimbabwe", '0x425' : "Estonian",
                 '0x438' : "Faroese", '0x429' : "Farsi", '0x464' : "Filipino", '0x040b' : "Finnish", '0x040c' : "French - France", '0x080c' : "French - Belgium",
                 '0x2c0c' : "French - Cameroon", '0x0c0c' : "French - Canada", '0x240c' : "French - Democratic Rep. of Congo", '0x300c' : "French - Cote d'Ivoire",
                 '0x3c0c' : "French - Haiti", '0x140c' : "French - Luxembourg", '0x340c' : "French - Mali", '0x180c' : "French - Monaco", '0x380c' : "French - Morocco",
                 '0xe40c' : "French - North Africa", '0x200c' : "French - Reunion", '0x280c' : "French - Senegal", '0x100c' : "French - Switzerland", 
                 '0x1c0c' : "French - West Indies", '0x462' : "Frisian - Netherlands", '0x467' : "Fulfulde - Nigeria", '0x042f' : "FYRO Macedonian", '0x083c' : "Gaelic (Ireland)",
                 '0x043c' : "Gaelic (Scotland)", '0x456' : "Galician", '0x437' : "Georgian", '0x407' : "German - Germany", '0x0c07' : "German - Austria", '0x1407' : "German - Liechtenstein",
                 '0x1007' : "German - Luxembourg", '0x807' : "German - Switzerland", '0x408' : "Greek", '0x474' : "Guarani - Paraguay", '0x447' : "Gujarati", '0x468' : "Hausa - Nigeria",
                 '0x475' : "Hawaiian - United States", '0x040d' : "Hebrew", '0x439' : "Hindi", '0x040e' : "Hungarian", '0x469' : "Ibibio - Nigeria", '0x040f' : "Icelandic",
                 '0x470' : "Igbo - Nigeria", '0x421' : "Indonesian", '0x045d' : "Inuktitut", '0x410' : "Italian - Italy", '0x810' : "Italian - Switzerland", '0x411' : "Japanese",
                 '0x044b' : "Kannada", '0x471' : "Kanuri - Nigeria", '0x860' : "Kashmiri", '0x460' : "Kashmiri (Arabic)", '0x043f' : "Kazakh", '0x453' : "Khmer", '0x457' : "Konkani",
                 '0x412' : "Korean", '0x440' : "Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)", '0x454' : "Lao", '0x476' : "Latin", '0x426' : "Latvian", '0x427' : "Lithuanian", '0x043e' : "Malay - Malaysia",
                 '0x083e' : "Malay - Brunei Darussalam", '0x044c' : "Malayalam", '0x043a' : "Maltese", '0x458' : "Manipuri", '0x481' : "Maori - New Zealand", '0x044e' : "Marathi",
                 '0x450' : "Mongolian (Cyrillic)", '0x850' : "Mongolian (Mongolian)", '0x461' : "Nepali", '0x861' : "Nepali - India", '0x414' : "Norwegian (Bokmål)", 
                 '0x814' : "Norwegian (Nynorsk)", '0x448' : "Oriya", '0x472' : "Oromo", '0x479' : "Papiamentu", '0x463' : "Pashto", '0x415' : "Polish", '0x416' : "Portuguese - Brazil",
                 '0x816' : "Portuguese - Portugal", '0x446' : "Punjabi", '0x846' : "Punjabi (Pakistan)", '0x046B' : "Quecha - Bolivia", '0x086B' : "Quecha - Ecuador", 
                 '0x0C6B' : "Quecha - Peru", '0x417' : "Rhaeto-Romanic", '0x418' : "Romanian", '0x818' : "Romanian - Moldava", '0x419' : "Russian", '0x819' : "Russian - Moldava",
                 '0x043b' : "Sami (Lappish)", '0x044f' : "Sanskrit", '0x046c' : "Sepedi", '0x0c1a' : "Serbian (Cyrillic)", '0x081a' : "Serbian (Latin)", '0x459' : "Sindhi - India",
                 '0x859' : "Sindhi - Pakistan", '0x045b' : "Sinhalese - Sri Lanka", '0x041b' : "Slovak", '0x424' : "Slovenian", '0x477' : "Somali", '0x042e' : "Sorbian", 
                 '0x0c0a' : "Spanish - Spain (Modern Sort)", '0x040a' : "Spanish - Spain (Traditional Sort)", '0x2c0a' : "Spanish - Argentina", '0x400a' : "Spanish - Bolivia",
                 '0x340a' : "Spanish - Chile", '0x240a' : "Spanish - Colombia", '0x140a' : "Spanish - Costa Rica", '0x1c0a' : "Spanish - Dominican Republic", 
                 '0x300a' : "Spanish - Ecuador", '0x440a' : "Spanish - El Salvador", '0x100a' : "Spanish - Guatemala", '0x480a' : "Spanish - Honduras", '0xe40a' : "Spanish - Latin America",
                 '0x080a' : "Spanish - Mexico", '0x4c0a' : "Spanish - Nicaragua", '0x180a' : "Spanish - Panama", '0x3c0a' : "Spanish - Paraguay", '0x280a' : "Spanish - Peru",
                 '0x500a' : "Spanish - Puerto Rico", '0x540a' : "Spanish - United States", '0x380a' : "Spanish - Uruguay", '0x200a' : "Spanish - Venezuela", '0x430' : "Sutu",
                 '0x441' : "Swahili", '0x041d' : "Swedish", '0x081d' : "Swedish - Finland", '0x045a' : "Syriac", '0x428' : "Tajik", '0x045f' : "Tamazight (Arabic)", 
                 '0x085f' : "Tamazight (Latin)", '0x449' : "Tamil", '0x444' : "Tatar", '0x044a' : "Telugu", '0x041e' : "Thai", '0x851' : "Tibetan - Bhutan", 
                 '0x451' : "Tibetan - People's Republic of China", '0x873' : "Tigrigna - Eritrea", '0x473' : "Tigrigna - Ethiopia", '0x431' : "Tsonga", '0x432' : "Tswana",
                 '0x041f' : "Turkish", '0x442' : "Turkmen", '0x480' : "Uighur - China", '0x422' : "Ukrainian", '0x420' : "Urdu", '0x820' : "Urdu - India", '0x843' : "Uzbek (Cyrillic)",
                 '0x443' : "Uzbek (Latin)", '0x433' : "Venda", '0x042a' : "Vietnamese", '0x452' : "Welsh", '0x434' : "Xhosa", '0x478' : "Yi", '0x043d' : "Yiddish", '0x046a' : "Yoruba",
                 '0x435' : "Zulu", '0x04ff' : "HID (Human Interface Device)"
                 }

    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

    # Get the current active window handle
    handle = user32.GetForegroundWindow()

    # Get the thread id from that window handle
    threadid = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, 0)

    # Get the keyboard layout id from the threadid
    layout_id = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(threadid)

    # Extract the keyboard language id from the keyboard layout id
    language_id = layout_id & (2 ** 16 - 1)

    # Convert the keyboard language id from decimal to hexadecimal
    language_id_hex = hex(language_id)

    # Check if the hex value is in the dictionary.
    if language_id_hex in languages.keys():
        return languages[language_id_hex]
    else:
        # Return language id hexadecimal value if not found.
        return str(language_id_hex)
```

Comment: It's better to give an explanation about the answer.