# Replacing keystrokes using Python

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events

I use a multilingual keyboard. Sometimes I write something in one language, forgetting to switch the keyboard layout (e.g. Alt+Shift in Windows) and getting gibberish, which I then erase, switch languauges and rewrite.

I thought of writing a script that replaces highlighted text automatically and assign a keyboard shortcut to it (in Linux). This is intended as a recreational project, and I'm a programming noob, so I don't yet know how to do most of it and I don't have code to share.

My concrete question is (assuming Python, but I haven't started yet so willing to consider alternatives):

**Is there an efficient way to map keystrokes in one layout with keystrokes in another layout?**

Right now my default idea is to create an explicit table of replacements, e.g. a<->ש, b<->נ etc.
But this would be neither pleasant nor elegant.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'll emphasize that I'm not asking about how to perform the actual replacement (e.g. via a dicitionary if using Python), but rather if there is a way to **avoid** writing an **explicit** table (dictionary or whatever) for each character in my keyboard.

For example, if there is a way to say "given the layout ENG (US), the letter 'a' corresponds to this phyiscal key right here on the left side of the keyboard, and this physical key, when using the HEB layout, corresponds to the letter ש".

If there's a way to do such a thing, I can write something like `keyID = GetKeyID(char,layout)` followed by `altchar = GetChar(keyID,altlayout)`.

I hope this makes sense. Note this was only an *example* of what I might hope for, I'd be happy to hear other ideas!

Comment: The most basic thing that comes into my mind would be to intercept all the keystrokes you want to intercept and then translate them with a dictionary.

Comment: This idea assumes I know when I want to intercept my keystrokes, though, right? If so, this is not what I have in mind. I want whenever I accidentally use the wrong layout, to map my gibberish-string to its equivalent string in the correct layout.

Comment: I suppose you can do that, too. I don't know if there's a way to make a Python program detect when keyboard layout is changed though, you'd have to investigate whether a module that helps in that sense exists or if it is doable with standard Python modules. If there is a way to do that, you simply run the script in the background and allow it to fix your accidental layout change for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem is not with how to get Python to identify there exists some text that needs to be replaced (as I understand, there's a way to simulate Ctrl+C). Instead, it is how to identify which character in one layout corresponds to which character in an alternative layout, without ardously constructing an explicit list of pairs of characters for the entire keyboard.

Comment: As I said, you can use a dictionary, where every key is the input text, and the value is the output text. They exist for a reason. Regarding detection of keyboard layout switching, I found out simply by googling that you can use ctypes. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047253/how-to-detect-current-keyboard-language-in-python) will prove useful.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking. I understand what dictionaries are, and I'm not asking about layout detection. I am asking if it is possible to avoid explicitly writing dozens and dozens of pairs of characters into a dictionary. I was hoping there is some method that, given a character, its layout and the intended layout, can give me the corresponding character in the intended layout. If there is no such method, I agree that an explicit dictionary is a reasonable choice, but my question is precisely: is there an alternative?

Comment: How would you map the entire keyboard following a specific criteria? It's not something that can be derived from something else. You might translate each character into its ASCII representation, and work with that number incrementation/decrementation if you want to numerically map characters, but the way you implement such a thing is up to you.