# parse date string with only locale as parameter in python

Tags: python, date, parsing, locale

I'm trying to parse date strings.

All I have is a string and a locale code, as in "en_EN" or "de_DE". The string and the locale is arbitrary so hardcoding a format is not a solution.

Normally this is no problem. I would use locale.nl_langinfo() to get the formatting. However, it doesn't exist on windows.

Since I don't want to update a string format dictionary every time I want to support a locale, is there either a library that will give me the date format string for the locale or just do the parsing based on the locale code?

Every library I've found requires the date format string.
Help please :)

edit: At this point I would take just a dictionary of locales and corresponding date formats

Comment: @chemicalwill I don't generate the dates. I'm parsing strings which might be "13.1.2020" or "1.13.2020" and the only indication for the format would be a parameter "en_US" or "en_EN".

Comment: What do you mean by: _it doesn't work on windows._ ? Is there any error ? Accrdoign to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.nl_langinfo): **This function is not available on all systems, and the set of possible options might also vary across platforms**

Comment: @MauriceMeyer exactly, the function does not exist on windows. Which is why I'm looking for an alternative. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect the OS default language in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425294/how-to-detect-the-os-default-language-in-python)

Comment: Not really, what i have are date strings and a corresponding locale string. The way I would use nl_langinfo() would be to first set the locale to whatever the locale string is, then call nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT) to get the date format. What I'm looking for is a way to turn for example "de_DE" into '%d.%m.%Y', which is the date format.

Answer (score 0):

Windows locale can be read using ctypes, as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425294/how-to-detect-the-os-default-language-in-python).
Additionally, you need to set locale explicitly to get the locale's default date format:

```
import locale
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()
for loc in ('de_DE', 'ja_JP', 'en_US'):
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,f'{loc}.UTF-8')
    date_format = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
    print(f"{loc} >> {today.strftime(date_format)}")
```

Out:

```
de_DE >> 09.04.2021
ja_JP >> 2021/04/09
en_US >> 04/09/2021
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but as i said, locale.nl_langinfo() doesn't exist on windows. 
Since the code is going to run on linux, I'll just write the code and hope there are no errors, as I can't debug it on windows.