List all actual microphones python
How can I list every actual microphones currently available in python?
Currently i am doing this:
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

print("Available audio input devices:")
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print(f"{i}: {dev_info['name']}")

device_index = int(input("Enter the index of the audio input device you want to use: "))

I know this also prints output devices, but the results are bloated with duplicates and things that aren't actually devices.
For reference I have 3 input devices, and 2 output devices, but the script prints 29 items.
What is the proper way of 'filtering' this to only display actual devices, aka the ones available in my Settings > System > Sound ?

Due to PortAudio supporting multiple APIs, you see repeated mentions of the same device but on different host APIs (for reference: https://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html). You can simply filter it out like this:
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print("Number of devices (all APIs, input + output):"+ pa.get_device_count())

for i in range (pa.get_device_count()):
   device_info = pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)
   if device_info['maxInputChannels'] != 0 and device_info['hostApi'] == 0:
       print('Device ' + str(i) + ': ' + device_info['name'])

I'm sure there's an even shorter way to do it, but essentially, it comes down to which native audio APi your application wants/needs and you count the number of input devices with the same API.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution but it works.
import pyaudio

#Check language replace with microphone_check_string = "" if you don't want language functionality
from sys import platform

import os

microphone_check_string = ""

if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2" or platform == "darwin":
    #get os language in linux or macos
    language = os.environ['LANG']
elif platform == "win32":
    #get os language in windows
    import ctypes
    import locale
    locale.getlocale()
    windll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
    windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage()
    language = locale.windows_locale[ windll.GetUserDefaultUILanguage() ]

#remove character encoding for linux or macos
if("UTF-8" in language):
    language = language.replace(".UTF-8", "")

#Translate the "Microphone" text to desired language
match language:
    case "en_US"  : 
        microphone_check_string = "Microphone"
#End check language

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

devices = p.get_device_count()

#list of device objects(dicts)
device_list = []

#list of device names. Used for detecting duplicates
temp_name_list = []

for i in range(devices):
   # Get the device info
   device_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
   # Check if this device is a microphone (an input device)
   if device_info.get('maxInputChannels') > 0:
        #get device name
        device_name = device_info.get("name")
        #check if device is duplicate
        if(device_name not in temp_name_list and microphone_check_string in device_name):
            #add device to device list
            device_list.append(device_info)
            #add device to name list
            temp_name_list.append(device_name)

#print device names
for pos, device in enumerate(device_list):
   print(f"{pos}: {device["name"]}")

list_len = len(device_list)

#handle user input
while True:
    device_user_selected = int(input("Enter the number of the audio input device you want to use: "))
    
    if(device_user_selected < 0 or device_user_selected >= list_len):
        print("Please select a device that is in the list.")
    else:
        break

#do device select logic
#retrieve device info by doing device_list[device_user_selected]

print(device_list[device_user_selected])

I used code from this tutorial and added my own logic to remove duplicates and make the user input more robust.
This is the output that I get:
0: Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
1: Microphone (Razer Seiren X)
2: Microphone (High Definition Aud
3: Primary Sound Capture Driver
4: Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)
5: Microphone (HD Audio Microphone)
Enter the number of the audio input device you want to use: 1
{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Microphone (Razer Seiren X)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

To get even better results add the following condition "Microphone" in device_name to the condition that checks if the device is a duplicate.
Edit: Added language functionality so that the string that is checked for can be changed depending on os language. If you want to disable this set microphone_check_string = "" before pyaudio is initialized and it won't string check the name of the device.
Please reference this stack overflow answer for info about checking OS language in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691701/19097807
And this answer for determining the host OS in python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220141/19097807
Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue or if you need help with anything else.

Not convinced that you should check for "Microphone" if this app needs to run on client devices, on which the language might not be English

You do have a good point. I added functionality to check the OS language. I tested across Windows, MacOS, and Linux.
