# How can I get the system language in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, posix, locale

How can I get the system language in C/C++? Like en_US or en_GB.

Comment: Which system platform?  Windows, Linux, other?

Comment: I use Linux. I'd like it to be POSIX compliant atleast.

Comment: What do you plan to use the information for?

Comment: To autodetect the language for when I'm parsing desktop files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a POSIX system, it looks like setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL); would return the current locale.

Comment: @Jookia: that also changes the locale to the user-specified locale (as determined by the environment).

Answer (score 7):

Generally you don't -- rather, you (usually) want to just conform to what it asks for using the nameless locale (i.e., `std::locale("");` will give you the locale of the user's choosing).

Answer (score 6):

Dup of [Find out the language windows was installed as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953416/find-out-the-language-windows-was-installed-as)

In summary - "the Win32 function you want is GetSystemDefaultUILanguage()" (assuming Windows of course)

Comment: OP doesn't say specifically Windows.

Comment: Actually, now he says Linux.  Thankfully I don't have enough karma to officially dup posts.

Comment: +1 even if OP commented about POSIX, it might be useful to others finding the question through Google

Answer (score 0):

There isn't necessarily one system language; individual "facets" of the locale can be configured separately.  It's all done with environment variables; http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/locale/ has a partial list of variables and their meanings.