# Internationalization based on system locale in applications in C++

Tags: c++

I came across this question for an internship

"Create an example console application in C++/Linux, that supports seamless Internationalization.  For example, if you are creating a multiplication table program; the messages you show on screen for getting the input, the log messages, the output messages should be internationalized based on the system locale."

Could anyone please explain me the problem elaborately...
Please answer asap...

Comment: Are you allowed to use any libraries you want, or is this some kind of homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Basically they want you show that you can somehow find out how to detect the system locale and from there create a simple console application which switches the displayed text according to the locale information.

I suggest starting here:

[How can I get the system language in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702665/how-can-i-get-the-system-language-in-c-c)